# Variance of a difference in marginal proportions in a three-way contingency table

Tags: estimation, mathematical-statistics, variance, covariance

Let a multivariate distribution be given by $P(Y,S_1,S_2)$, where all three variables are discrete, $Y$ is multivalued, $S_1=(0,1)$ and $S_2=(0,1)$, respectively, and all may be dependent. Define the quantity $X$ for difference in means on categry $j$ of $Y$ as

$$X=E(Y=j|S_1=1)-E(Y=j|S_2=1).$$

To give some background to this statistic, assume $S_1$ and $S_2$ are response indicators that indicate whether $Y$ is observed or not observed, e.g. in two indepdent surveys. $S_1$ and $S_2$ may be dependent, because the probability of response in two different surveys should be assumed correlated within the same individual. $X$ then provides the population difference in $Y$ between response groups to both surveys.

I estimate $X$ by

$$\bar{x_1}=\frac{1}{\sum _{i=1}^{n}S_{1i}}\sum _{i=1}^{n} I(Y_i=j)S_{1i}-\frac{1}{\sum _{i=1}^{n}S_{2i}}\sum _{i=1}^{n} I(Y_i=j)S_{2i},$$

where $I$ is the indicator function and the sum is taken over a sample of size $n$, where $i=1,..,n$. This is the differene in marginal (sample) proportions in category $j$ of a three-way contingency table made up by $P(Y,S_1,S_2)$, let's say $p_{1j}$ and $p_{2j}$. The goal is to derive the standard error for the difference between both quantities. We have:

$$\text{Var}(p_{1j}-p_{2j})=\text{Var}(p_{1j})+\text{Var}(p_{2j})-2\text{Cov}(p_{1j},p_{2j})$$

I know how to estimate the variance parts of the formula (i.e., $p_{1j}(1-p_{1j}/n_1$)), but I am clueless about the covariance. The covariance of a multinomial variable is $-n\pi_k\pi_l$ where $\pi$ is the population proportion and $k$ and $l$ two categories. But I do not think this formula applies here.

Thank you for advice on where to move from here.

Comment: Do you just need the sample covariance between two indicators?

Comment: I need the standard error of $\bar{x_1}$. This supposes I can derive the sample covariance $\text{Cov}(p_{1j},p_{2j})$.

Comment: Which boils down to the covariance between two indicator random variables, right?

Comment: @MichaelMayer I am not sure; I get as far as: $Cov(p_{1j},p_{2j})=E(p_{1j}p_{2j})-\pi_{1j}\pi_{2j}$ where $E(p_{1j}p_{2j})$ is equal to the expectation of the product of the two components of $\bar{x_1}$. But I cannot simplify this product any further.